# HBase row key design: matching either of two columns

Tags: mysql, hbase

I have some data which contains columns `colA` and `colB`, among others. For any row, values in `colA` and `colB` are different.

I get queries like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE colA = X or colB = X`. To optimize, I indexed `colA` and `colB` in MySQL.

---

Now, I want to build this database in HBase, serving the same queries. But I understand HBase has no indexes, and that I need to design good row keys.

I thought of this approach:

Duplicate each row in MySQL. For one copy, use `colA + randomString` as row key. For the other, use `colB + randomString`. (Append random string because each row key must be unique).

- Good: I only need one query. i.e return all rows where row key has prefix `X`
- Bad: I double the size of the database

What could be an alternative approach that is more space efficient, while maintaining performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you have outlined is good enough. HBase is columnar and can employ prefix compression, which combined with gzip block compression will ensure that the on-disk size is not actually double of your useful data size.

As a matter of fact, even if you had a way of storing a single row with two different columns (and doing the query you want to do), HBase would still be storing the row key twice for each column internally. Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326717/hbase-create-multiple-tables-or-single-table-with-many-columns/51352632#51352632) for an example of how HBase stores data in a HFile. In short, HBase stores the full row key with every single value (though prefix compression takes care of amortising this cost). You'll find a similar storage model in most columnar databases primarily due to the fact that they are columnar and need to store row key with each column.

So, to answer your question, your approach is perfectly fine. Though I would add the original column identifiers separated by a delimiter (instead of a random string) to the row key in case you need to select value for only one of the columns in future. Even better, put column identifiers as prefix (rather than suffix) of the row key and then you could pass row key filters (separated by OR) and your setup scales to any number of columns where you could select a subset of columns and still maintain performance.

An alternative approach to looking at it is employing HBase power to do millions of writes per second but still maintaining the original relational view while querying data. This essentially means that you need secondary indexes on columns of interest. [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/) provides all that to you on top of HBase; it is a very active project and provides the best of both worlds (write intensive power of HBase and SQL like filtering of data) with the added storage cost of secondary indexes (that you anyway pay in any relational database).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a HBase table with a columnfamily having all columns same as your mysql table.

HBase supports `SingleColumnValueFilter` filter to filter the records based on column value. You can compare value of ColA and ColB with `OR` operator.

Hence there is no need to add any prefix or suffix in your row key.

Comment: This is a terrible idea to use in a large scale HBase cluster. Column value filter will have to look at each and every key value in and HBase row key range (or the whole table if no key range is passed). This essentially means that you are reading all values for these two columns for every query.